# json_encode() throwing an error: "Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument"

Tags: php, json, utf-8

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  json_encode() [<a href='function.json-encode'>function.json-encode</a>]: Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/share.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 130</p>
```

It used to work before, version php 5 [which i believe is the latest major PHP version].

Comment: What is the string being decoded

Comment: Display the "invalid" thingie using `echo bin2hex(...)` so we can help you figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`json_encode` only allows `UTF-8` characters to be encoding. Looks like the data you are trying to encode may have non `UTF-8` characters.

So, you should first convert the string/data into UTF-8 and then do the encoding.

```
mb_convert_encoding($string,'UTF-8','UTF-8');
json_encode($string);
```

Comment: "mb_convert_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"

Comment: The error is self explanatory I guess. You need to send a string to convert. Not an array.

Comment: but i need to array to go through in order for my site to function correctly. is there any way to convert an array?

Comment: Convert all array elements for UTF-8? Use `foreach` together with  `mb_convert_encoding`.