# How to get rid of json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, utf-8

I am getting this warning and the php returns null .

> PHP Warning:  json_encode(): Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in
>   /var/www/rreadyreckoner/get_instruction.php on line 26
>   {"result":[{"instruction":null}]}

I am trying to run this php script.

```
<?php 
include "demo_config.php";
$con = mysqli_connect($server_name,$mysql_user,$mysql_pass,$dbname);
 if(!$con)
 {
         echo "Connection Error".mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 else{
//echo "";
 }

$query ="SELECT instruction FROM `rreadyreckoner` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
                  array_push($result,
                  array('instruction'=>$row[0]));
}
if(!$result)
{
echo "Nothing to display";
}else
{
echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The only change I did was when inserting content into mysql database removed a character that was getting inserted by default and replaced it with nothing.

```
$instruction =$_POST["instruction"];
$plainHTML = str_replace(chr(194),"",$instruction);
$sql = "INSERT INTO rreadyreckoner (id, instruction)
VALUES (NULL, '$plainHTML')";
```

Before doing this I was getting a proper response.
Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, "utf8");
```

after `mysql connect`.

Comment: This adds {&quot;result&quot;:[{&quot;instruction&quot;:&quot;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0&lt;\/head&gt;\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0\n\n\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 and \n characters how can I get rid of them.

Comment: Have you saw that answer of Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/a/30363698/3081659

Answer (score 0):

```
$t = json_encode($s, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

avoids the `\u....` stuff.

Don't use `mb_encode`, etc.

`194` is hex `C2` which is a common first byte in utf8 sequences.

See [Trouble with utf8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for more discussion on what needs to be done.  In particular, check the `SELECT HEX...` technique to see if data is stored correctly.

Back to the title...  Can you provide the invalid sequence you are dealing with?  You can do something like `echo bin2hex(...)` to get the hex of the naughty string.